# SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT doesn't notify when unplugging "disabled device"

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

Please, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Why `SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT` doesn't notify when plugging/unplugging "**disabled device**" (I mean disable device in device manager)?

If device is enabled, everything works fine.
Here is my source code:

- Register notification:

  ```
  m_hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(m_szServiceName, HandlerEx, NULL);
  if (m_hServiceStatus == NULL)
  {
      return;
  }

  DWORD dwState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
  SetServiceStatus(m_hServiceStatus, &dwState);

  // Register device notification
  DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE notificationFilter;
  ZeroMemory( &notificationFilter, sizeof(notificationFilter) );
  notificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE);
  notificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;

  if(NULL == (m_hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(m_hServiceStatus, &notificationFilter, DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE|DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES)))
  {
      return;
  }
  ```
- `HandlerEx` function:

  ```
  DWORD HandlerEx(DWORD dwOpcode, DWORD dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID /*lpContext*/) throw()
  {
      DWORD dwRes = ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
      switch (dwOpcode)
      {
      case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
          if (m_hDevNotify)
          {
              UnregisterDeviceNotification(m_hDevNotify);
              m_hDevNotify = NULL;                
          }
          dwRes = NO_ERROR;
          break;
      case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
          if (m_hDevNotify)
          {
              UnregisterDeviceNotification(m_hDevNotify);
              m_hDevNotify = NULL;
          }
          dwRes = NO_ERROR;
          break;
      case SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT:
          {
              // ToDo: process event notification
              dwRes = NO_ERROR;
          }
          break;
      default:
          break;
      }
      return dwRes;
  }
  ```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: The first event would be DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL but that fires only when the device becomes available, which will never happen if its disabled. I would not expect a disabled device to be the source of any notifications.

Comment: I tried WM_DEVICECHANGE in another application. And it is notified when disabled device is plugged/unplugged by DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363211(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's not listed as one of the messages HandlerEx is dispatched for SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683241(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks. So, I have to use WM_DEVICECHANGE.

Comment: But there is a little bit confused information "There is no additional information about which device has been added to or removed from the system. Applications that require more information should register for device notification using the **RegisterDeviceNotification** function." on page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363211(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: There is no way to get a specific device from DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED, so when you get the message you need to see what devices are available, but I guess if the device is disabled your back to the original problem